# CSS: adapting the total height of several form elements to the browser window by changing only the height of a textarea

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

What I am trying to achieve is shown here:

[image: smaller]

and here, after increasing the height of the browser window:

[image]

The container (in the red border) takes up a fixed percentage of the browser window height.
The form elements should also occupy a fixed percentage of the container, but only by changing the height of the "Content" textarea.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, setting Content textarea height to this ( the next snippet is pseudo code ):

## Content.height = #Main_Textarea.height - #SaveButton.offsetHeight - #Title.offsetHeight - ...

(the rest of your elements in textarea great div), using **offsetHeight**.
From what I understand, the textarea div is height resizable, so Content's height is changing.

You can make it doc.getElemById("Textarea").addEvListener("resize", function() { #Content.height = #Main_Textarea.height - #SaveButton.offsetHeight - #Title.offsetHeight - ... });

I hope it is ok

Comment: If you are able to help me, i would have a problem too:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/53995876/10840299